# How are swarms considered in terms of number of creatures?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, saving-throw, dnd-adventurers-league, swarm

There is, in Adventurers League Dnd, a monster statblock with the following ability :

> At the start of his turn, every living creature within 100 feet must succeed on a DC 15 Constitution saving throw or they lose 5 hit points and [he] regains 5 hit points.

That monster also has an ability to spawn Swarms of Rot Grubs (Medium swarms of Tiny Beasts). I am thus wondering how those two abilities interact.

More generally : how are swarms considered vis-à-vis creatures ?

1. Considered as a single creature [here, would be a single CON save]
2. Considered as many creatures (how do you say how many?) [here, would be X CON saves]
3. Considered as no creature [here, would be 0 CON saves]

Comment: Related questions that all ask this question implicitly or explicitly: "[What does Sacred Flame do to a swarm?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/123287)" and "[What happens when you cast the Polymorph spell on a swarm?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/144569)" and "[Can swarms be pushed or pulled?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72757)" and "[Can a Druid Wild Shape into a Swarm or "Giant"?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/45991)" and "[Can a wizard have a swarm of animals as a familiar?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/126044)"

Comment: Other related questions (they ask this implicitly or explicitly): "[Can a Beast Master ranger choose a swarm as an animal companion?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/153769)" and "[Can the Conjure Animals spell summon swarms?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/129335)"

Comment: Is G.Moylan's answer good enough for the green check?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Swarms are (implicitly) treated as singular creatures

All of the information we need to mechanically handle a given monster is provided in its [stat block](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#MonsterStatistics):

> A monster's statistics, sometimes referred to as its stat block, provide the essential information that you need to run the monster.

Stat blocks will also explicitly provide special saving throw information [when it is present](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#SavingThrows).

Next, we can look in the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf) on page 16 for a confirmation that swarms are indeed groups (in an answer about the *conjure animals* spell):

> ... swarms are groups of creatures.

**However**, given that swarms are listed as their own stat blocks in the Monster Manual, we must consider that those stat blocks are treated the same as any other, and would therefore make saves, attacks, etc. in a similar fashion to obviously singular entities. A swarm's stat block *represents* multiple creatures but is treated as a *single* creature.

Importantly, note that the stat block doesn't detail how many creatures are in a given swarm, only that the attacks can differ when the swarm drops below half its starting HP (as detailed in the attacks for a given swarm). We *could* say that the HP represents how many creatures are in a swarm, but that would only be an interpretation, not a rule, and shouldn't change how we handle rolls.

**In short**: While Swarms clearly are *groups* of creatures, they are listed as stat blocks in the Monster Manual, et al., so treat them the same as any other *singular* creature with a stat block.

In your specific scenario, we go with option 1:

> Considered as a single creature [here, would be a single CON save]

Answer (score 14):

Swarms are counted as a **singular** creature, but they have a few differences to non-swarms.

1. They are able to occupy another creature’s space (and vice versa)
2. They are unable to regain hit points or gain temporary hit points
3. They are able to move through a space large enough for a singular creature of their size (tiny in this case)

Of course, you could always play it differently, if you like, but RAW, the swarm would only make one saving throw.

Comment: Are you basing this on the stat block being, in the MM, each creature has a stat block?

Comment: This answer claims that it is the RAW answer, but it cites exactly zero rules.

Answer (score 6):

There is a wrinkle to answering your question that I think should be addressed as well. **While swarms, in your case, would be considered a singular creature,** they are also majorly considered a group of creatures.

I have noticed many people debate and ask if a swarm is considered a single creature for purposes such as a [Druid's wildshape](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/689153233357418496?s=20)(1), or Conjure Animals, which [Jeremy Crawford (1), Mike Mearls (2), and Christopher Perkins(3) has spoken out on this](https://twitter.com/mikemearls/status/1000126777837015040?s=20)(2) matter [adamantly](https://twitter.com/ChrisPerkinsDnD/status/610606967896174592?s=20)(3) stating that they are a ***swarm*** and not applicable as an individual creature.

*However*, in your case, you are asking about saving throws and such, which falls into the category of how the swarm interacts with the world and how they are formed. In this case, we must look at them, according to [a tweet by Jeremy Crawford,](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/552612829597929472?s=20)(1) as many animals bound together. As such, they have  a single HP to calculate, and not a collective of them, so they would work as if they are in a symbiotic relationship where they cannot exist seperate.

Likewise, hitting a swarm with a spell, like Burning Hands, would hit them as a group, not allowing stragglers.

Comment: Can you find another source than the now-unofficial tweets? At the very least, you might point out that the tweets aren't official rulings but might speak to intent. The site you link to is an unofficial compilation site and has no official affiliation with D&D, Crawford, or the rules.

Comment: Probably best to change the URLs to the direct twitter rather than through the 3rd party website.

Comment: Did not know Sage Advice wasn't considered official, but as suggested, but I did change them to the direct tweets and clarified who said what.

Comment: @VictorB The "Sage Advice Compendium" _is_ an official, public document used to adjudicate and interpret the rules. The Sage Advice website, though similarly named for Crawford's tweets, is not official and never has been. His tweets are no longer official, too, after long history of contradictory or confusing rulings

Comment: @G.Moylan I did not know it was two different things. However, are you saying that Crawford's tweeted answers are not official making my whole reply invalid?

Comment: @VictorB See the “Official Rulings” segment [here](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf). You can still often use his tweets, as they speak to intent, but it’s best to 1) acknowledge that in the answer, and 2) find something RAW or SAC if possible

Answer (score -9):

Swarms are not singular creatures.  Swarms are collections of creatures.

This is clear from every single text that describes what a swarm is, and what a creature is.

The rules for creatures list a set of types, which do not include swarms.  Swarms state they are collections of creatures.

A spell that says "target eyeball become blind" would work on a human being who has an eyeball, spells that target creatures work on swarms.

In this case, "every creature" becomes a bit of a problem, as the rot grubs would consist of many creatures.  How a DM handles that is going to require adjudication, but the most sane way is to slightly misapply the general rule from spell stacking; all of the effects happen at once, so only the most powerful applies, and it applies once.

In this case, it is one effect, so the swarm makes one saving throw if 1 or more of its creatures are in the region, and suffers the effect of the failure/success.

Similarly, the creatures of a swarm (while in the swarm) share HP; so spells that deal HP damage to a creature damage the entire swarm.  Spells that damage every creature in an area use the "do the effect once".  On the other hand, you could argue that spells that kill a single creature only kill one creature in the swarm.

Comment: You should cite relevant evidence/experience to support your claims. See this meta: [What are the citation expectations of answers on RPG Stack Exchange?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8696/33569)

Comment: @v2bl I did cite the rules.  See paragraph 3.  It just is an unpopular reading of the rules.  It happens, I am ok with it.  Beeps answer, in contrast, cites no rules, but is popular with many upvotes.  And no mod advising reading basic SO expectations.

Comment: Or by cite, are you meaning quote?  Quoting that much text wouldnpt be legal, as it is a long list, and it is the absence of swarm from the list that is of note.

Comment: You don't need to quote the entire list - what I mean is that (for instance) you say "the rules for creatures", but not which rules/where they can be found (e.g. book and page number/section). Likewise, your answer makes a number of other claims but doesn't necessarily cite any particular rules that support those claims.